# Bazel build - go:generate stringer "stringer: can't happen: constant is not an integer"

Tags: go, bazel, auto-generate, bazel-rules

I am trying to create an auto-generated file "txstatus_string.go" within Bazel sandbox which relies [on a go file](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/blob/master/pkg/workload/schemachange/schemachange.go) and it is getting created with below stringer command:

```
go:generate stringer -type TxStatus
```

I am using a bazel genrule like this:

```
genrule(
name = "gen-txstatus-stringer",
srcs = [
    "schemachange.go",
],
outs = ["txstatus_string.go"],
cmd = """
   GO_REL_PATH=`dirname $(location @go_sdk//:bin/go)`
   GO_ABS_PATH=`cd $$GO_REL_PATH && pwd`
   env PATH=$$GO_ABS_PATH HOME=$(GENDIR) \
   $(location @org_golang_x_tools//cmd/stringer:stringer) -output=$@ \
   -type=TxStatus $(location schemachange.go)
""",
tools = [
    "@go_sdk//:bin/go",
    "@org_golang_x_tools//cmd/stringer",
],
```

)

But not sure why in this case stringer is failing due to "stringer: can't happen: constant is not an integer" Any one has a better idea on how to approach or why this is happening?

I already created some other stringer files using a common `stringer` genrule and everything goes well.

If you want to go deeper in code this is an [opensource Github repo](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pull/61266), that you can go and check =)

Comment: Have you tried building without stringer?  I'm thinking you have a dependency issue with github.com/jackc/pgx

Comment: Is the stringer tool up to date? This works on the cli, but it does look like stringer is not resolving the correct types from pgx.

Comment: I also tried adding `github.com/jackc/pgx` inside `tools` in my `genrule`, but it is still failing. @HymnsForDisco

Comment: The version I am using for pgx is: v3.6.2+incompatible but even if I tried with v4.6.0 is failing. I might be adding them wrong, possibly? @JimB

Comment: It looks like you are not using go modules, or not using them correctly, which stringer is going to need to resolve that dependency correctly. I can only replicate the error using `GO111MODULE=off`.

Comment: I think should be something like that, a friend of mine was able to replicate the error https://github.com/pitakill/stringertest and then solve it only running `go get` as with that command go will modify `go.{mod, sum}`and will install all the dependencies. @JimB